# SQL Oracle - Return message if all rows are 'None' otherwise return row. Do not return 'None'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with cus and rus. For some cus there are many rows but all of the rus are none. In this case I would like to return a message, e.g. "no ru unit." For cus that have rus I would like to return their rows. But not the rows that have none for rus....

I made up some data to work with. In this case I should get all rows for cu-1, one row with the message for cu-2, and three rows for cu-3.

```
create table cu_ru ( 
    cu varchar2(30), 
    ru varchar2(30) 
)

insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-1', 'ru-1b');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-1', 'ru-1a');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-2', 'None');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-2', 'None');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-2', 'None');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-3', 'ru-3a');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-3', 'None');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-3', 'None');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-3', 'ru-3b');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-3', 'ru-3c');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-3', 'None');
insert into cu_ru (cu, ru) values ('cu-3', 'None');
```

My not working effort:

```
select distinct t.cu,
(case when 
(
select count(cu) 
from cu_ru
where ru not like 'None'
and cu = t.cu
group by cu
) is null
then 'no ru unit' else ru end) as ru
from cu_ru t
order by cu, ru
```

The output is:

```
CU      RU
cu-1    ru-1a
cu-1    ru-1b
cu-2    no ru unit
cu-3    None
cu-3    ru-3a
cu-3    ru-3b
cu-3    ru-3c
```

How can I drop "cu-3 None" from my output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
SQL> select cu, decode(ru, 'None', 'no ru unit', ru) ru
  2  from (select distinct cu, ru,
  3          count(distinct ru) over (partition by cu) cdr
  4        from cu_ru
  5       )
  6  group by cu, ru, cdr
  7  having sum(decode(ru, 'None', 1, 0)) = 0
  8      or cdr = 1
  9  order by 1, 2;

CU                             RU
------------------------------ ------------------------------
cu-1                           ru-1a
cu-1                           ru-1b
cu-2                           no ru unit
cu-3                           ru-3a
cu-3                           ru-3b
cu-3                           ru-3c

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks Littlefoot! Now I just have to understand why :)

Comment: LOL! Run the inline view first so that you'd see what it returns. Then you'll understand the HAVING clause. BTW, you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

This is a simplified variation of @Littlefoot's query using Standard SQL, should run in any DBMS supporting Windowed Aggregates:

```
SELECT cu,
   CASE WHEN ru = 'None' THEN 'no ru unit' ELSE ru end
FROM
 ( -- get distinct cu/ru combinations
   SELECT cu, ru,
      -- check if there's any other value besides None for a cu
      MAX(CASE WHEN ru <> 'None' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      Over (PARTITION BY cu) AS OtherFlag
   FROM cu_ru
   GROUP BY cu, ru
 ) dt
WHERE ru <> 'None'   -- don't show None 
   OR OtherFlag = 0  -- unless there's only None
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I'm inclined to think:

```
select cr.*
from cu_ru cr
where cr.ru <> 'None'
union all
select distinct cr.cu, 'None'
from cu_ru cr
where cr.ru = 'None' and
      not exists (select 1 from cu_ru cr2 where cr2.cu = cr.cu and cr2.ru <> 'None');
```

**[EDITED by LF, to show that it really returns 3 rows for CU_2]**

```
SQL> select cr.*
  2  from cu_ru cr
  3  where cr.ru <> 'None'
  4  union all
  5  select cr.cu, 'None'
  6  from cu_ru cr
  7  where not exists (select 1 from cu_ru cr2 where cr2.cu = cr.cu and cr2.ru <> 'None');

CU                             RU
------------------------------ ------------------------------
cu-1                           ru-1b
cu-1                           ru-1a
cu-3                           ru-3a
cu-3                           ru-3b
cu-3                           ru-3c
cu-2                           None
cu-2                           None
cu-2                           None

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! It is giving me this error ORA-00904: "CR"."CU": invalid identifier. But I think I see what your approach is.

Comment: Line 6 misses table alias, i.e. should be `from cu_ru cr` but - nonetheless - that query would return 3 rows for CU_2 (which isn't what you, @fallingdog, asked).

Comment: @Littlefoot . . . How would it return 3 rows for "CU_2"?

Comment: @Gordon, I edited your answer to show what happens on my 11gR2 - there really are 3 CU-2 rows. No problem if you delete code I added once you see the result.

Comment: @Littlefoot: Either add `DISTINCT` to the 2nd SELECT or remove the `ALL`

Comment: @dnoeth, I'm just saying that query - "as is" - doesn't return what it should. Yes, it should / could be modified, but I don't feel like modifying Gordon's query.